# Nginx Load Balance not working for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, nginx

i have a NodeJS Script and want to run the users with Load Balance from NGINX on it.

I give out in NodeJS the address

```
console.log(server.address());
```

This gives back

```
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 2055 }
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 2055 }
{ address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 2055 }
```

everytime the same port, for all users. 20-30 on the site.
But why all same?

Thats my nginx settings

```
upstream nodes {
    ip_hash;

    server localhost:2055;
    server localhost:2056 weight=5;
    server localhost:2057;
}
```

i also give 2056 more weight for test, but no one on other server than 2055...
And sure, i do `service nginx reload` after changes.

Thats my location from the site in nginx

```
location / {
            add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*" always;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_pass http://nodes;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

And thats the servers i start on nodejs

```
server.listen(2055);
server.listen(2056);
server.listen(2057);
```

thats at the end of the code (bottom)
I mean, the site is working but server.address() gives 2055 back only.

I put that here

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {  
    console.log(server.address());
```

Any Ideas how to check if that is only a log error and how to check if the other ports running or something?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html)

> With ip-hash, the client’s IP address is used as a hashing key to determine what server in a server group should be selected for the client’s requests. This method ensures that the requests from the same client will always be directed to the same server except when this server is unavailable.

So change

```
upstream nodes {
   ip_hash;

   server localhost:2055;
   server localhost:2056 weight=5;
   server localhost:2057;
}
```

to

```
upstream nodes {
   server localhost:2055;
   server localhost:2056 weight=5;
   server localhost:2057;
}
```

Which should give you a weighted load balance.

Comment: Oh okay. But what i found out is, that the nodes listeners 2056 and 2057 are not running for any reason... think thats the main reason